# Is there a way to render a custom react component for all paragraphs tags?

Tags: reactjs, components

Like with mdx in react, we can specify a provider in which we can specify which components to render for mdx primitives. Is there a way in react where we can specify some custom react component for let's say all the paragraphs element or it could really be any other html primitive?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. To do so, you have to create a component and pass there.

```
<Paragraph span={<Additional />} />
```

Now, in Paragraph,

```
return (
  <>
  <p>Loren ipsum</p>
  {props.span}
  </>
)
```